# how to destroy an object completely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

please help to destroy, in whole self.area

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import sys


class TP(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x', expand = 'yes')
        self.parent = parent
        self.make_menu_bar()

    def make_menu_bar(self):
        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self) 
        self.parent.config(menu = self.menubar)                           

        self.file = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.file.add_command(label = 'New', command = lambda: self.toggle_area(True))
        self.file.add_command(label = 'Close...', command = lambda: self.toggle_area(False))
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = self.file)

    def toggle_area(self, action):
        if action:
            self.area = tkinter.Text(self)
            self.area.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')
            print(sys.getrefcount(self.area))
        else:
            print(sys.getrefcount(self.area))
            self.area.destroy()
            print(sys.getrefcount(self.area))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    TP(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

the problem is that after I select the menu item "Close", the screen shows the number of references to the object self.area. number of references to the object self.area still not 0, and 2. that is, the object is in memory and is not garbage collected

Comment: You don't want the object to (forcibly) disappear from memory. That is simply memory unsafe, and it does not at all characterize the effect you want to achieve. If you want to stop some widgets from drawing, that has nothing to do with freeing memory. In fact, deleting the object without stopping it from being drawn would just lead to nonsense being drawn, or even crashes.

Comment: I'm no expert on these but have you tried `pack_forget()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if you can do `sys.getrefcount(someReferenceToAnObject)` then you still have *some reference to an object*, so the reference count cannot be zero.

That being said, garbage collection is never immediate, so the actual collection of that object may happen much later. You really shouldn’t worry about it though. As soon as you recreate a `tkinter.Text` at that point, the old is probably completely gone and up for garbage collection.

That being said, if you want to reduce the reference count, you probably want to do `del self.area` after destroying it too.

Comment: If he really wanted that reference gone could he just import gc and manually run garbage collection? I think that would be HUGE overkill, but would achieve the objective.

Comment: Manually running the garbage collection will just trigger it but won’t guarantee that the object will be collected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have not just to call `self.area.destroy()`, but to detach from `self.area` by doing `del self.area` of `self.area = None`. That would remove a reference from the `TP` instance. However, `TP` is likely to be destroyed very soon, so this is not a problem. Though it's not enough, apparently, the `root` object holds a reference to your `Text` object (maybe not directly).

Anyway, there is nothing to worry about. In CPython (that is the most widely used implementation of Python) garbage collection is done in a way that causes immediate deletion of an object with zero reference counter. However, it is not guaranteed that such a behavior takes place everywhere. Probably the objects may be deleted much, much later even if there are no references to them. And there is no portable way to enforce immediate destruction.